# Uncaught Type Error cannot read properties of undefined reading (forEach)

Tags: javascript, html, css

So, I put in code to generate a masonry grid and once I got to the point of writing the forEach loop, the code broke down and wouldn't display the grid. I was following a tutorial and wrote everything as instructed but for whatever reason, it wouldn't work. Here is the forEach loop I wrote:

```
 const container = document.querySelector('.container');

function generateMasonryGrid(columns, posts){
   container.innerHTML = ''
    console.log(posts)
   // Store all columns arrays with relevant posts
   let columnWrappers = {};

   // creates columns and adds this to columnWrapper obj
   for(let i = 0; i < columns; i++){
       columnWrappers[`column${i}`] = []
   }
   
   for(let i=0; i< posts.length; i++){
     const column = i % columns;
     columnWrappers[`column${column}`].push(posts[i])
   }
   
   for(let i = 0; i < columns; i++ ){
       let columnPosts = columnWrappers[`columns${i}`];
       let column = document.createElement('div');
       column.classList.add('column');

       columnPosts.forEach( post => {
               let postDiv = document.createElement('div');
               postDiv.classList.add('post');
               let image = document.createElement('img');
               image.src = post.image;
               let overlay = document.createElement('div');
               overlay.classList.add('overlay');
               let title = document.createElement('h3');
               title.innerText = post.title;

               overlay.appendChild(title);
               postDiv.appendChild(image, overlay);
               column.appendChild(postDiv);


           }) 
           container.appendChild(column)
       
   }
}

generateMasonryGrid(4, posts)
```

N/B: For context, 'posts' is an array defined in a separate css file. column is defined separately as well.

What should I do to fix this?

Comment: `forEach` won't work because `columnPosts` is not an array.

Comment: I don’t understand how a css file can define an array. Please add relevant HTML to your snippet as currently it’s impossible for us to tell what is a collection, what is an array etc.

Comment: Hello, I got the answer to my question. Sorry to say it was something as simple as a typo. I appreciate your efforts to help though!